# npm lodash install issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am trying to install lodash through npm on a project and every time I try to install it for my project I get this err:

> D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store>npm install --save lodash
>   npm ERR! path D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM
>   npm ERR! errno -4048
>   npm ERR! syscall unlink
>   npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
>   npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
>   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
>   npm ERR!   path: 'D:\github\sandbox\NgRx-Store\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Perry Craft\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-10T21_35_04_683Z-debug.log

Is there any ways to install lodash and @types/lodash another way it is for an Angular 4 project.

Comment: Seems that a problem with permissions, you are in windows, i don't know much about permissions in that, but maybe you can focus in what i'm saying

Comment: sandbox === vagrant?

Comment: sandbox is just the name of the folder when I am messing around maybe a tutorial or something new I learned and I am just trying it out. Never had a problem with permissions before but I didn't think about trying on a different project! I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened with me. So, Try re-installing NodeJS and run `npm install` again.
After that try, `npm i -g npm` and finally install `npm i --save lodash`. Hope this works for you also.

---

Otherwise, try downloading the file locally from https://lodash.com/ or try to use the CDN.